# How to use same public and private keys across instances when scaling out in Azure App Service - Linux - PHP

Tags: php, azure, openssl, azure-web-app-service

I have a PHP app on Azure App Service running azure linux.

On my local machine I created public-private key pair using openssl and used the keys in JWT authentication flow

access token creation

```
$private_key = file_get_contents(ROOTPATH . 'localkey.pem');
$access_payload = [...];
$access_token = JWT::encode($access_payload, $private_key, 'RS256');
```

access token verification

```
$public_key = file_get_contents(ROOTPATH . 'localkey.pub');
$decoded_token = JWT::decode($access_token, new Key($public_key, 'RS256'));
```

I created the public-private key pair on Azure App Service instance by logging in via SSH.

Now how to use the same public-private key pairs across instances when scaling out? Will the `.pub` and `.pem` files gets copied to every instance when using auto-scaling? What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

> Now how to use the same public-private key pairs across instances when
> scaling out? Will the  `.pub`  and  `.pem`  files gets copied to every
> instance when using auto-scaling? What is the recommended way?

By default Azure Auto-scale will use the default configuration and it will dynamically scale your instances and remove them when not needed.

You can make use of **Azure Key vault** to store your Public and Private Keys and use them to authenticate with App Service.

I deployed one PHP App in azure and created one Azure Key Vault Instance like below:-

I created a managed Identity for my Azure App service and provided it Owner role to the Resource group where my App service and Key vault is deployed like below:-

[image]

[image]

Provided the same managed identity access to the Key vault Keys and I have also added one Service Principal with name Powershell  in the Access policies to use it later in the PHP code to authenticate the keys for App.

Create secrets with keys value stored inside it, Like below:-

[image]

Access Policy:-

[image]

Use below code to authenticate your Azure App service managed Identity with key vault :-

```php
use Azure\Identity\ManagedIdentityCredential;

use Azure\SecurityCenter\SecretsClient;

  

$managedIdentityClientId = 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9d57-e63ca3946c62';

  

// Create a ManagedIdentityCredential to authenticate with the specified managed identity

$credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential($managedIdentityClientId);

  

// Create a SecretsClient to access the Key Vault

$keyVaultName = 'keyvaultphp';

$secretName = 'phpkeyapp';

$secretsClient = new SecretsClient('https://'.$keyVaultName.'.vault.azure.net', $credential);

  

// Retrieve the public and private keys from the Key Vault

$publicKey = $secretsClient->getSecret($secretName.'-public')->getValue();

$privateKey = $secretsClient->getSecret($secretName.'-private')->getValue();

  

// Use the keys for JWT token creation and verification

$access_payload = [...];

$access_token = JWT::encode($access_payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');

$decoded_token = JWT::decode($access_token, new Key($publicKey, 'RS256'));
```

You can also authenticate with Service principal with the code below:-

Add AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET in the App service configuration:-

[image]

```php
use Azure\Identity\ClientSecretCredential;
use Azure\SecurityCenter\SecretsClient;

// Get the credentials for the service principal
$clientId = getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_ID');
$clientSecret = getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET');
$credential = new ClientSecretCredential($tenantId, $clientId, $clientSecret);

// Create a SecretsClient to access the Key Vault
$keyVaultName = 'mykeyvault';
$secretName = 'mykey';
$secretsClient = new SecretsClient('https://'.$keyVaultName.'.vault.azure.net', $credential);

// Retrieve the public and private keys from the Key Vault
$publicKey = $secretsClient->getSecret($secretName.'-public')->getValue();
$privateKey = $secretsClient->getSecret($secretName.'-private')->getValue();
```

Alternatively you can add **WEBSITE_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY** with the contents of Public Key in the Configuration settings of your web app so that the Apps Service uses this key.

[image]

Save the settings and restart your web app.

[Use Key Vault from App Service with Azure Managed Identity - Code Samples | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/)

Comment: Instead of hitting the key vault for every request, I would like to try to fetch keys and create localkey.pub and localkey.pem files using a php script. I will try to invoke this php script from custom startup command. I'll update how it worked